# Inequality involving integrals of trigonometric functions

Tags: integration, inequality, riemann-integration, integral-inequality

> Prove the inequality 
>   $$\left|\int_0 ^{\pi/4} \frac{\tan x~dx}{3-\sin(x^2)}\right|≤ \frac{1}{4}\log_e 2.$$

I have tried many different ways to get this inequality but failed.

Answer (score 3):

For $x\in [0,\pi/4]$, we have that $\sin(x^2)\leq 1$ and $\tan(x)\geq 0$. Therefore $3-\sin(x^2)\geq 2$ and 
$$0\leq \int_0 ^{\pi/4} \frac{\tan(x)}{3-\sin(x^2)}\,dx\leq  \int_0 ^{\pi/4} \frac{\tan(x)}{2}\,dx.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Sure I can. Thank You.

Comment: @AkashBanerjee Fine. Please edit your post and show your progress under your question.
BTW recall that the person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted". See math.stackexchange.com/tour